# Matlab Mexfiles and Cuda: Evaluate function handle

Tags: function, matlab, cuda, handle, mex

Hey there,
I have a mex file which I want to parallelize with the help of CUDA. The current functionality is: I pass a function handle and a huge number of 'points' to the mex file and it evaluates the function on each of the points in sequential mode (on the CPU). It therefor uses something like:

```
mxArray* y;
const mxArray *e[2] = {functionHandle, point};
mexCallMATLAB(1, &y, 2, (mxArray **)e, "feval");
```

to evaluate the function Handle on the point using the matlab-function feval. Now I wonder what happens when I try to parallelize the calculations via CUDA: Will this work correctly? Because if the evaluation with mexCallMATLAB is done on the CPU, there won't be any benefit using CUDA. But how to do it than? I can't imagine any way to evaluate a function handle on a certain point in C directly without using the matlab-function feval...

Thanks so far!
You'll help me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `mexCallMATLAB` will not be callable from the GPU. In general, host-side calls cannot be made from within the body of a CUDA Kernel.

You may find that if you have access to [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/), you can use [GPUArrays](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html) with [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bsic4n4-1.html). For example, if the function you wish to evaluate across many points looks like this:

```
function y = myFcn( x )
y = 1;
for ii = 1:10
  y = sin(x * y);
end
```

Then you could call this on the GPU like so:

```
gx = gpuArray( rand(1000) );
gy = arrayfun( @myFcn, gx );
```

Comment: Woah thanks, I think this is the post I was looking for! Just the question now: How can I access this from my mex-file if I can't use `mexCallMATLAB` out of the CUDA kernel?

Comment: Actually, my suggestion is really not to use a CUDA kernel directly, but to use the arrayfun method as an alternative. If you have existing CUDA code that you wish to run from within MATLAB, Parallel Computing Toolbox supports a "CUDAKernel" object to help with that.